# QPainterPath - moving/deleting Elements

Tags: python, qt, graphics, pyside

Is there any way to edit the position of individual 'lineTo' elements in a QPainterPath (or remove particular elements and replace them with a modified version?).  I've tried using *.setElementPositionAt(i,x,y) to no avail (the path is not redrawn).

I basically want to all users to edit the vertices of a polyline (created via a qpainterpath and lineTo methodology) dynamically with the mouse.

Obviously, if there is a better way to create polylines in a QGraphicscene then some advice on that would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are using the `setElementPositionAt` but it works. The trick with `QGraphicsScene` is that [`addPath`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsscene.html#addPath) returns a `QGraphicsPathItem`, and you need to update that item with the modified `QPainterPath` using the its [`setPath`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicspathitem.html#setPath) method.

A simple example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0,0,100,100)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Move path')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.movePath)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.createPath()

    def createPath(self):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()

        path.moveTo(25, 25)
        path.lineTo(25, 75)
        path.lineTo(75, 75)
        path.lineTo(75, 25)
        path.lineTo(25, 25)

        self.pathItem = self.scene.addPath(path)

    def movePath(self):
        # get the path
        path = self.pathItem.path()

        # change some elements
        # element 0: moveTo(25, 25)
        # element 1: lineTo(25, 75)
        # element 2: lineTo(75, 75)
        # ...
        path.setElementPositionAt(2, 90, 85)
        path.setElementPositionAt(3, 90, 15)

        # set the new path
        self.pathItem.setPath(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Widget()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Many many thanks, that was really helpful. I was using a QGraphicsPathItem, but for some reason when I went straight to addPath/setPath on the scene, the whole thing worked.  I also made some other changes thanks to your example.  Fantastic.  Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for Avaris. He find time to show exact example. That's real value.